# Use of "arrive" or "reach" for payment

Tags: word-choice

If I want to confirm receiving payment with the sender, can I use verbs like *reach* and *arrive*? For example,

> The payment/money has **reached** us.
>
> The payment/money has **arrived**.

Are there better ways to say it?

Answer (score 6):

A better option would be:

We received the money.

or

We received the payment.

Comment: I think I would say, "We have received your payment" or "Your payment has been received."

Comment: Yes that is a more 'friendly' way to say it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Both of those are valid. You could also use the passive voice construction *been received*.

Comment: *Arrived and reached* are both valid but could not be used in this context, unless the money is dilvered by a real person to your doorsteps.